# Acer Aspire ES1-512 touchpad not working after clean Windows 8.1 Pro (re-)installation

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, bios, touchpad, acer-aspire

On an older laptop Acer Aspire ES1-512 the touchpad is not working after clean Windows 8.1 Pro (re-)installation.

---

Things that could play role here:

- Right from the beginning of Windows 8.1 Pro installation USB boot (UEFI mode) the touchpad does not work.
- After the installation finished, I merely thought I'd install missing drivers with Driver Booster or similar tool, did not help.
- There are yet about 150 updates available, none of which has Synaptic or Elantech in its name, (and I don't want to linger for hours just waiting).
- If I unattach my USB mouse I see no pointing device in the Device Manager, it's not only disabled, it's unrecognized probably.

Comment: No problem. :) It just surprised me, being a Linux user myself since primary school. When I install Windows from scratch I always download all the required drivers and install them according to the 'best practices', starting with the chipset whenever applicable, then graphics then all the others in no particular order except when there's a specific recommendation (in one laptop we have to install Bluetooth before sound).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I do not usually have time to download each up-to-date driver separately. I am an IT guy who gets the business done as fast as possible. Time is money. I admit I use Driver Booster since the version which passes all drivers through [WHQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/whql-release-signature) + at least I review each version of those drivers if there is correct manufacturer, and I find it perfectly valid approach for businesses which save a lot of time = money with this tool. I usually recommend users buying a PRO version afterwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually only solved the problem was going into the BIOS and make one change:

---

1. Repeatedly **press** <kbd>F2</kbd> after turning the laptop on (without <kbd>Fn</kbd>). I suppose you are in the BIOS by now.
2. In the main menu go onto the second tab called **Main**.
3. Now, in this very tab you should find the **Touchpad** item.
4. Switch it to **Basic**.
5. Go onto the last tab called **Exit**.
6. Choose **Exit saving changes**.
7. After your laptop boots - this time, just this time - after logging in, **press** <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> **once** to enable the touchpad device.
8. You are **done**! Your touchpad should work just fine now.

---

**Disclaimer**: I fixed this computer problem this way exactly, there might be other ways. Since it's customer's laptop, I won't *play with it* any longer to find out. Good luck!